# With Dask the tensorflow can only detect 1 GPU from the machine which has 2 GPU installed

Tags: dask

Our HPC node has 2 K80 GPUs. When I run following code on the HPC node using python, the code will detect 2 GPUs and display "gpu device types:['TeslaK80', 'TeslaK80']"

But when  I run the same code with DASK, it can only detect 1 GPU. It displays "gpu device types:['TeslaK80']"

Following is the code to detect GPU
    import tensorflow as tf

```
def init_gpu()
    print("\n\n\n ... tensorflow version = ", tf.__version__)
    from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

    local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
    print("local device protos:{0}".format(local_device_protos))
    _gpu_raw_info =  [(x.name,x.physical_device_desc) for x in local_device_protos if x.device_type == 'GPU']
    print("gpu raw info:{0}".format(_gpu_raw_info))
    _gpu_names =  [x[0] for x in _gpu_raw_info]
    _gpu_devices =  [x[1] for x in _gpu_raw_info]
    _gpu_device_types =  [x.split(':')[2].split(',')[0].replace(' ','') for x in _gpu_devices]
     print("gpu device types:{0}".format(_gpu_device_types))
```

Following is the DASK LSF cluster code to launch job on the cluster:

```
cluster = LSFCluster(queue=queue_name, project=hpc_project, alltime='80:00', cores=1, processes=1, local_directory='dask-worker-space', memory='250GB', job_extra=['-gpu "num=2"'], log_directory='scheduler_log', dashboard_address=':8787'))
cluster.scale(1* 1)
client = Client(cluster.scheduler_address, timeout=60)
wbsd_results = []
r = dask.delayed(init_gpu)()
wbsd_results.append(r)
client.compute(wbsd, sync=True)
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm that when you run an LSF job without dask the job can see both GPUs ?  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_gpu/lsf_gpu_legacy_elim.html has some example which may be of use

Comment: If I use LSF job without DASK, I got 1 GPU as well. It must be LSF setting. Thanks.